# Regex matching up to a character if it occurs

Tags: java, regex

I need to match string as below:

1. match everything upto `;`
2. If `-` occurs, match only upto `-` excluding `-`

For e.g. :

- `abc;` should return `abc`
- `abc-xyz;` should return `abc`

`Pattern.compile("^(?<string>.*?);$");`

Using above i can achieve half. but dont know how to change this pattern to achieve the second requirement. How do i change `.*?` so that it stops at forst occurance of `-`

I am not good with regex. Any help would be great.

**EDIT**

I need to capture it as group. i cant change it since there many other patterns to match and capture. Its only part of it that i have posted.

Code looks something like below.

```
public static final Pattern findString = Pattern.compile("^(?<string>.*?);$");
if(findString.find())
    {
        return findString.group("string"); //cant change anything here.

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use a negated char class.

```
^[^-;]*
```

ie.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^-;]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

This would match any character at the start but not of `-` or `;`, zero or more times.

Comment: For most use cases, even the leading `^` is unnecessary.

Comment: You mean the one at the start? No it must.

Comment: @Holger if the first `^` isn't there, then it also matches `xyz` from `abc-xyz;`

Comment: Only if you call `find` a second time but why should you do that if only a single match (at the beginning) is intended?

Comment: @Keppil: the pattern of this answer is not suitable for `matches` as it doesn’t account the trailing part that is to be ignored. The only reasonable use is a single invocation of `find`.

Comment: we may also use `replaceall` ,`str.replaceAll("-.*|;.*", "");`

Comment: Why not `str.replaceFirst("[;-].*", "")`?

Comment: @Keppil: the `^` and `$` of the original question are also obsolete, if the OP is using `matches`. And I think, it is up to the OP, to tell how he’s going to use that pattern…

Comment: It it possible to make the pattern grouped as `string` as in the question. That where i am facing the problem. `pattern.group("string");` would return the result. That something which i cant compromise with :(

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for:

`[^-;]*`

It matches characters that are not `-` or `;`.

Tipp: If you don't feel sure with regular expressions there are great online solutions to test your input, e.g. https://regex101.com/

Comment: what if `-` is not present. It will keep searching for `-` and finally will not match.

Comment: Ah, I thought you only wanted to match if `-` is present. I adjusted the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I see you have an issue in the code since you try to access `.group` in the `Pattern` object, while you need to use the `.group` method of the `Matcher` object:

```
public static String GetTheGroup(String str) {
    Pattern findString = Pattern.compile("(?s)^(?<string>.*?)[;-]");
    Matcher matcher = findString.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        return matcher.group("string"); //you have to change something here.
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

And call it as

```
System.out.println(GetTheGroup("abc-xyz;"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pMPWTR)

**OLD ANSWER**

Your `^(?<string>.*?);$` regex only matches 0 or more characters other than a newline from the beginning up to the first `;` that is the last character in the string. I guess it is not what you expect.

You should learn more about using [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regex, as you can match 1 symbol from a *specified character set* that is defined with `[...]`.

You can achieve this with a `String.split` taking the first element only and a `[;-]` regex that matches a `;` or `-` literally:

```
String res = "abc-xyz;".split("[;-]")[0];
System.out.println(res);
```

Or with `replaceAll` with `(?s)[;-].*$` regex (that matches the first `;` or `-` and then anything up to the end of string:

```
res = "abc-xyz;".replaceAll("(?s)[;-].*$", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/E0aqB4)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution without removing groupings.

- `(?<string>.*?)`   matches everything upto next grouping pattern
- `(?:-.*?)?`   followed by a non grouping pattern starts with `-` and comes zero or once.
- `;` end character.

So putting all together:

```
    public static final Pattern findString = Pattern.compile("^(?<string>.*?)(?:-.*?)?;$");
    if(findString.find())
    {
       return findString.group("string"); //cant change anything here.
    }
```